# compile error when implement a simple generic function in java?

Tags: java, generics

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayAlgorithm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ;
    }


    public static <T> T findMax(T[]a)
    {
        T max=a[0];
        for (T t : a) {
            if(max<t)   //this line generate compile error
                max=t;
        }
        return max;
    }

}
```

In line : `if(max<t)` generate error : operator < is not defined for arguments T

After I search google, it seems I should make comparable such thing which is too complex for a simple task.Because I just want to achieve simple findmax(primitive arrays).

Any suggestion to make this compile error go away or how to easily achieve this simple findmax(primitive arrays)?

Comment: Generics don't work with primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `findMax` method is generic, using the declared type variable `T` as the type of the single method parameter. Since the type parameter doesn't have any generic bounds, within the method, it can be considered at most an `Object`.

The operator `<` (and its relatives) cannot be applied to reference types (except some `Number` subtypes).

Generics don't apply to primitive types so you won't be able to call your method with arrays of primitive types.

You'll have to overload the method for each primitive type array.

For reference types, make sure they are `Comparable` by adding a bound to `T` and use `compareTo`.

Comment: public static <T extends Number> T findMax(T[]a) why this also doesn't work? Still same error.Because I thought T as subtype of Number should support <?

Comment: @AlexWei Note how I had said _some_ `Number` subtypes. Those are the wrapper types for all the numerical primitives. The `<` and `>` operators would work with them, but not as generic. You can't get this behavior with generics for all numerical types.

Comment: The < operator is not defined for any Object including Number subclasses. It happens to work where auto unboxing converts to primitives but the reason has nothing to do with Number or generics